# FactoryGirls randomly fails with 'Factory not registered', why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I've some tests that randomly fail, approx. 20% of times. It means that WITHOUT changing the code, each time that I run the tests 1 time out of 5 will fail with "Factory not registered" error. It's very weird.. :(

This is the consone output:

```
Failures:

  1) Unit#new_from_string returns factor for metric conversions
     Failure/Error: FactoryGirl.create :taza
     ArgumentError:
       Factory not registered: taza
     # ./spec/models/unit_spec.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.29619 seconds
4 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/unit_spec.rb:22 # Unit#new_from_string returns factor for metric conversions

Randomized with seed 61727
```

And this is the code:

file: "unit_spec.rb"

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Unit, "#new_from_string" do
  it "parses the string and returns a Unit object" do
    [some tests...]

    FactoryGirl.find_definitions
    u = FactoryGirl.create :taza
    FactoryGirl.create :tbsp

    [tests...]
  end

  it "returns factor for metric conversions" do
    [tests not involving factory girl...]

    # the following is line 29, that fails
    FactoryGirl.create :taza

    [tests...]   
  end
end
```

file "spec/factories/units.rb":

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :taza , :class => CustomUnit do
    singular 'taza'
    plural 'tazas'
    physical_type Unit::VOLUME
    equivalence_factor 200
    equivalence_unit 'ml'
  end

 [other factories...]      
end
```

Comment: In `spec_helper` are you `require`ing the factory files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is on this line

```
FactoryGirl.find_definitions
```

Actually there is no need for this line when your factories are in correct directories(I see it is), and you put `gem factory_girl_rails` in Gemfile.

I think, 20% of time, the second test get run at first. At this time, there is no definition of Factory and the test failed. The other test has such definition and get passed. In other time, the first test run first so definition exists.

My suggestion:

1. Make sure you have `factory_girl_rails`, not `factory_girl` in Gemfile.
2. Remove that line of definition.
3. [optional but recommended] Put all definition in a single file `spec/factories` and remove all other factory files, if you don't have too much factories. This would be easier to manage.

Comment: It seems to work! thanks!!
small note: in Gemfile I added:
gem 'factory_girl_rails', github: 'thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails'